# Flink S3 Unknown Host Exception

Tags: java, kubernetes, amazon-s3, apache-flink, ceph

I have a flink Job that's run on flink environment we deployed with helm on kubernetes cluster.

The job uses rocksdb s3(ceph) state backend.
But every once in a while the pod can't reach the host name and we get the error below

Root exception

```java
Caused by:java.net.UnknownHostException: HOSTNAME: Name or service not know
```

the error above is the cause of

```java
java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext
```

and

```java
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore operator state backend for..
```

My guess that one of the pods suddnley can't acsess the s3 host.

But I can't figure out a way to prove that or to check if it's because something else..

Comment: The `UnknownHostException` usually provides name of the host it tries to resolve in Your case it tries to resolve `HOSTNAME:` itself, looks like You are not setting somekind of env var ?

Comment: I put the `HOSTNAME` as an example. I tried to resolve a real host name.